# Why some expression that looks like a definition for normal types unexpectedly turns out to be a declaration for templates?

Tags: c++, templates, declaration

These expressions are all definitions for normal types:

```
int num;
bool flag;
```

But some expression that looks like a definition for normal types unexpectedly turns out to be a declaration for templates(for details, see below and https://ibb.co/k0qCHp2)!

Here is the related code snippet(https://godbolt.org/z/a9W9Wc):

```
    #include<iostream>
    template<typename T>
    class Test
    {
    public:
        static constexpr int sdm = T(nullptr);
        static int f(void){static_assert(sizeof(T)==0);}
        int g(void){static_assert(sizeof(T)==0);}
    };
    
    int main()
    {
       Test<int> intTest;  //**O'DWYER says that it's a declaration instead of a definition in his talk(see https://ibb.co/k0qCHp2)! Why?** 
       //But I can get this object's address indeed.
       std::cout << &intTest << std::endl;
    }
```

If `Test<int> intTest;` is a declaration, I can draw the conclusion that `std::vector<int> vec;` and `std::map<std::string, int> map` are both declarations too. Am I right?

Comment: Well, yes, but why did you ***not*** expect `Test<int> intTest;` to compile, exactly?

Comment: The problem looks like not the declaration/definition but the implementation of the member functions. [https://wandbox.org/permlink/5pmfUGPRIUCn6ORG](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5pmfUGPRIUCn6ORG)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I think `Test<int> intTest;` is a definition just like `int a;`. The compiler should complan since there is a 'static_assert' expression.

Comment: Ah: one of the subtle features of templates is that member functions of a template class are not actually instantiated until they are ***used***. Merely instantiating a template class does ***not*** instantiate every method in the class. So, instantiate `Test<int>` to your heart's content, but don't dare call methods, because when ***they*** get instantaited, game over. See the dupe question.

Comment: @MikeCAT The key question is why this(i.e https://godbolt.org/z/j8f6dG) complies?

Comment: [Emphasize mine]: "one of the subtle features of templates is that **member functions** of a template class are not actually instantiated until they are used." It seems that not only member functions but also member variables. See `static constexpr int sdm = T(nullptr);`.

Comment: If your question is about member variables of a class template rather than member functions, please clarify that in the question.

Comment: @cigien The key question is whether ` Test<int> intTest;  `  is a  a declaration or a difination.  O'DWYER says that it's a declaration instead of a definition in his talk. Is it correct?

Comment: Hmm, there's a target for this somewhere I'm sure, but the current target is definitely wrong. @SamVarshavchik can you check and reopen?

Comment: @cigien @MikeCAT Since I can get this object's address(i.e `&intTest`) indeed. I think it should a definition instead of a declaration.

Comment: `Test<int> intTest;` is a definition (which is also a declaration; all definitions are also declarations) of the variable `intTest`, but I'm not sure why this matters, why you care so much about this point. What matters is this: "**[temp.inst]/2** The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes the implicit instantiation of the declarations, **but not of the definitions**, default arguments, or noexcept-specifiers of the class member functions, member classes, scoped member enumerations, static data members, member templates, and friends..." Emphasis mine.

Comment: And further: "**[temp.inst]/9** An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function template, a variable template, a member template, a non-virtual member function, a member class, a static data member of a class template, or a substatement of a constexpr if statement (9.4.1), unless such instantiation is required..."

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Please add an answer in the answer box instead of in comments. The question has been reopened since I don't think the target was accurate.

Comment: @cigien Well, it wasn't reopened at the time I posted those comments, so I had no choice.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That's true. In the future, please vote to reopen the question if you think it's not a duplicate. Since you have a C++ hammer, you can even do so single handedly.

Comment: Notice that `static_assert(sizeof(T)==0)` is as wrong as `static_assert(false)`. making the template ill-formed NDR. (but harder for compiler to detect).

Comment: @Jarod42 "ill-formed NDR"? What's "NDR" short for?It could not be found on https://www.abbreviations.com/ and https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/

Comment: Non diagnostic required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Test<int> intTest;` is a definition (which is also a declaration; all definitions are also declarations) of the variable `intTest`. However, this fact is rather irrelevant to your implied question of "why does this line compile". The reason it compiles is this: it causes an implicit instantiation of the class template specialization `Test<int>`, but **not** of its member functions and static data members.

> **[temp.inst]/2** The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes the implicit instantiation of the declarations, but not of the definitions, default arguments, or noexcept-specifiers of the class member functions, member classes, scoped member enumerations, static data members, member templates, and friends...

> **[temp.inst]/9** An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function template, a variable template, a member template, a non-virtual member function, a member class, a static data member of a class template, or a substatement of a constexpr if statement (9.4.1), unless such instantiation is required...

Those member functions and static data members will be implicitly instantiated when they themselves are used; it is at this point that the compiler will discover their definition is ill-formed, and issue appropriate diagnostic.

> **[temp.inst]/3** Unless a member of a class template or a member template has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires the member definition to exist; in particular, the initialization (and any associated side effects) of a static data member does not occur unless the static data member is itself used in a way that requires the definition of the static data member to exist.

Comment: O'DWYER says that it's a declaration instead of a definition in his talk(see https://ibb.co/k0qCHp2)! Is it wrong?

Comment: You are mis-reading their argument. The slide you cite does **not** say that `C<int> myvar;` is a declaration. It says that the line should cause the compiler to **instantiate** the declarations, but not the definitions, of members of `C<int>`. Which is consistent with the text of the standard - it's merely a short version of **[temp.inst]/2**

Comment: " instantiate the declarations, but not the definitions, of members of C<int>."? How to comprehend it in the right way?

Comment: Roughly, compile the `static int f(void);` part, but not the body of the function; until this function is actually called or otherwise used in a way that would require looking at its body.